# How to add a dependency without specifying a version with the maven package command

Tags: maven

I want to add additional parameters to the mvn package command to add the specified dependencies, but I can only specify the groupId and artifactId because I want the version to be consistent with the one specified in the dependencyManagement in the pom file.

For example, if I want to add the package spring-boot-starter-actuator, the parent artifactId of the pom file is spring-boot-starter-parent, so I don't want to specify a version.

Comment: Adding a dependency via command line is a bad idea. The question is why would you like to do that? Just define the spring boot parent and the dependencies within your pom file ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I am responsible for the company's monitoring. If I don't do this, I need to add spring-boot-starter-actuator dependencies to all the company's spring boot projects, which is more troublesome. Add dependencies on the command line.

Comment: @khmarbaise To add dependencies on the command line, I only need to configure the mvn command uniformly in a location such as jenkins.

Comment: The actuator should be added as a usual dependencies because that implies enhancements of the configuration/security setup for the applications so it is not enough ... and also this gives a difference between what you install and what you develop and can not check locally (for example via containers )? ...Added dependencies is simply wrong. It might be a better approach to define a company BOM/parent to handle such things.....

Comment: @khmarbaise But then I need the whole company's R&D to cooperate with me to modify the pom, although the changes are not big, but this will be a long time cycle, if I go directly from the command to solve, the time will be shorter.

Comment: simply answer in the end. No possible via command line. Long answer: As I already wrote it looks you are going the wrong path...If those dependencies are needed add them to the pom file ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Well thanks, in the end we also chose to add the dependency in the pom